# How to represent collections in HAL (JSON version) while following REST

Tags: json, web-services, rest, web, hateoas

Let's say I have a collection of books which we'll call a library.  GET domain.com/library should return a list of books in the library in HAL compliant JSON. How should I format the JSON? How could I embed the book resources? Here is the format I'm currently thinking about:

```
{
  "books": [
      {
          "name": "Fight Club",
          "_links": {
              "self": { 
                  "href": "domain.com/library/Fight-Club"
              },
           },
           ...
      },
       ....
  ],
  "_links" : {
       "search": { 
           "href": "domain.com/library/search"
       },
       ...
   },
   "_embedded" : {
       "Fight Club": {
           "author": "Chuck Palahniuk",
           ...
           [Same links as above]
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the HAL specification was written, the `_embedded` object is intended for sub-resources of a given resource. So your bare-bones HAL JSON would look like this.

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/library"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "item": [{
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "/library/Fight-Club"
                }
            },
            "author": "Chuck Palahniuk",
            "title":  "Fight Club"
        }]
    }
}
```

The immediate properties of the `_embedded` object are [link relations](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml). The `item` relation is a standard relation that means a resource is an item belonging to the context resource (in this case, your library). You can create custom link relation by using [CURIEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURIE).

Notice the lack of a `books` array in the top-level object. You may include it if you wish, but it's merely a convenience. A HAL library will only be aware of what you put in `_links` and `_embedded`. See this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/hal-discuss/bCzydTlHB3M/Fj0g3pwvJzsJ) regarding collections in HAL and the human factor in deciding where to put your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your answer + the discussion addressed all of my problems with HAL collections.

Comment: FYI if the # of books are huge, you may want to consider paging the collection and having the resource be a page.  The number of entries in the item embedded link would be limited to page size, and the _links would have next/previous links as needed.